# Solve the following PDE.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'd like to solve the following equation explicitly.

> $$ \begin{cases} u_{yy}(t,y)-t^{2}u(t,y)=f(t,y) & t\in\mathbb{R},\
> > 0<x<h\\ u(t,0)=0=u(t,h) \end{cases}, $$ where $f\in L^{2}$.

My textbook gives me a solution **without proof**. The solution looks like the integration form with a Kernel. Moreover, 
I think solving this equation is elementary, so I tried a little.
Let $u(t,y)=e^{ay}$, $a=\pm t$, so $u(t,y)=C_{1}(t)e^{ty}+C_{2}(t)e^{-ty}$.
And then I paused. If there is any recommendation book for me, I'll
be glad. Thanks in advance.

In my textbook, the solution is :

> $$ u(t,y)=\int_{0}^{h}K(t,y,z)f(t,z)\ dz, $$

where 
$$
K(t,y,z)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{it\sin ith}\sin ity\sin it(z-h) & z\ge y\\
\frac{1}{it\sin ith}\sin it(y-h)\sin itz & z\leq y
\end{cases}.
$$

Comment: Since there is a derivative wrt only one variable $y$ this is not a PDE, but an ODE (or equivalent to an ODE). Consider $t$ not as a variable, but as a parameter. Solve $u''(y)-t\,u(u)=f(y)$. Don't forget that the arbitrary constants of integration are arbitrary functions of the parameter $t$.

Comment: @JJacquelin I agree with your point. So I put my trial above. Please look at it. Plus, the answer is not the friendly form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this is now an ODE that is a boundary value problem, your solution has been written out in the form of a Greens Function solution. I would suggest checking out Sturm-Louiville theory if you are unfamiliar with this, but that choice of a Greens function $K$ can be found explicitly.